# visual studio 2012 - persist multiple solution explorer windows across VS sessions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, solution-explorer

I cannot find a way to persist my solution explorer windows (opened using the "New Solution Explorer View" after right clicking on a folder in the "base" solution explorer window).

This is really annoying because, when working for example with an mvc app, every time I start VS, I need to recreate a solution explorer window for Areas, for Views, for the various other projects in my solution, etc, etc.

The app is not ba.com, but it is isn't meandmydog.com either, so there are a lot of files and folders in the solution.

Comment: did you ever find a way of doing this? this bugs me all the flippin' time - especially when I have to unload the project to edit the .vbproj/.csproj file several times within a short period!

Comment: No, didn't find a solution to this.

Comment: Having the same troubles for almost the same reasons.. REALLY annoying.. VS 2012 Update 3 for me..

Comment: So we have VS 2015 now and this issue remains. Or has anyone found a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem with the project size and not VS. You should only need a single solution window because you can only have a single solution open at a time. A simple fix would be to create a separate solution (*.sln) containing the relevant projects (*.csproj/*.vbproj) for each of the "views" you need. This is a great approach because it helps you see what dependancies you have and also helps you filter what projects you need for which "app".

I hope this helps.